# Can't access route mapped by Controller

Tags: spring, tomcat, url-routing

I'm trying to map route /clock in a @Controller class, but all i'm getting is error 404 when testing locally, i'm using apache tomcat 8 and the module is synchronized.

Here is the link for my application class:

```
@EntityScan(basePackages = "br.ufpe.nti.model")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "br.ufpe.nti.controller.repository")
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "br.ufpe.nti")
public class SmartClockApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SmartClockApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And the controller is here:

```
@Controller
public class Routes
{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/clock", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<JSONObject> getClock()
    {
        DateFormat dateAndTime = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss");
        DateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        final HttpHeaders httpHeaders= new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        double angleHour = 0.5 * (60 * (cal.get(Calendar.HOUR) + 1) + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        double angleMinute = 6 * cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        double angle = Math.abs(angleHour - angleMinute);

        JSONObject response = new JSONObject();
        try {
            response.put("id", null);
            response.put("time", time.format(cal.getTime()));
            response.put("createdAt", dateAndTime.format(cal));
            response.put("angle", angle);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<JSONObject>(response, httpHeaders , HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I was told tomcat was supposed to show a message in console about routes mapped, but there is no such message.

Comment: are you looking for a json response, or a view?

Comment: The relevant code and error must be in the question itself. Not in a gist.

Comment: Do you see the other application start log messages like the spring banner? My guess is, that you didn't deploy the application into the root context but will find the route at /applicationname/clock

Comment: Can you please provide us the command that you are using to run the application? It should be something like `java -jar SmartClockApplication.jar`. You should not deploy this application to a Tomcat container as it is a Spring Boot app and it contains everything to run directly

Comment: Thanks Bruno, i was supposed to run SmartClockApplication.java.
The more you know!